# difference between static and dynamic indexing in a database / datawarehouse

Tags: database, bitmap, indexing, data-warehouse

what is the difference between **static and dynamic indexing** in a database ?and how we compute there IO costs ?

Answer (score 0):

OLTP (transactional databases) undergo more frequent updates compared to OLAP (date warehouse) . In OLTP, indexes which allows update frequently is better suited .Hence  dynamic indexing is better suited in these applications. In the data warehouse updates are less frequent and it used for read operations so a static index is applied here.

The classification of static and dynamic index don't seem to appear in documents and I assume it pertains to frequency of updating an index.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/dbms_indexing.htm